# How do I generate the same encrypted database password string value with crypt() and my salt?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, crypt

If `crypt()` generates a different string each time, how the heck am I supposed to combine a provided password and salt for the same encrypted password in the database?

I was thinking that I could generate a random salt for the crypt() method to combine with the users' provided input (id est `crypt(@_POST['password'],$salt)`) for encrypting the password. That generates an encrypted password for my database. I'm also storing that `$salt` in my database within a `salt` column.

I thought that I could call `crypt($_POST['providedPassword'],$saltStoredInDatabaseFromRegistrationTime)` to return the same encrypted value for the password I've stored in the database from the registration form, but it turns out that `crypt()` is returning a different value every time I call it.

How am I supposed to end up with the same encrypted value I have in my database for the password?

Comment: Do you have PHP 5.5? Use `password_hash()` instead; otherwise, use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: It doesn't matter. The generated hash may be different, but the end result is always the same given the same string. Why not use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and let it take care of everything for you, instead of storing a seperate salt? If less than 5.5, use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm storing the salt in the database, too, because I've read in many places that a hacker with access to the salt may be able to breach all of the passwords in the database if I use the same salt for each password. It's not that much trouble to ensure this extra security by fetching the salt and combining it with each password instead. Am I wrong?

Comment: That ^ would fall under the "Primarily opinion-based". I've seen some top/high ranked members here say that you could go either way, while others dispute it. I rather not get involved in *their* argument ;)

Comment: You don't need to store salts separately in your database, because `crypt()` hashes include the salt.

Comment: The other question is about `crypt()`, bcrypt is one of the algorithms implemented in `crypt()`. The answer to the other question illustrates in detail how hashes and salts are related to crypt, how to handle them and how "random salts", "different string each time" and "how the heck to combine" them work together. Yes, the guy that closed your question also wrote that answer because that guy remembered having explained that topic before. You can address that guy directly in the comments with @deceze.

Comment: @deceze You're answer wasn't helpful or relevant and I've already found the answer I needed here from Jack.

Answer (score 2):

The way `crypt()` works is like this:

```
// to create
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);

// to verify
if (crypt($password, $hash) == $hash) {
    // yay!
}
```

*Not exactly like that; `crypt()` has a variety of hash algorithms and it can return invalid hashes to indicate errors. Lastly, you should compare hashes using a comparison function that's not susceptible to timing attacks, such as the new `hash_equals()`*

**Note:** It's important to *always* generate a new salt every time you hash something with `crypt()`.

That said, since PHP 5.5 you should hash passwords using [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/password_verify); for earlier versions you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library.

Comment: *for earlier versions...* - PHP >= 5.3.7